# HBase Table Model

Tags: database-design, hbase

I'm learning how to use HBase. I need to put in the database each trip of several cars (by points geolocated (`x`,`y`)). These data come in a JSON Format.

The problem is that the number of points geolocated during the trip change for each document that I recover. (Each trip is different.)

How can I store these data in HBase?

Do I have to change the number of columns for each row inserted?

- Trip1 : x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3
- Trip2 : x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4

Or Do I need to keep only 2 columns, one for all `x` and one for all `y`?

- Trip1 : (X,Y)
- Trip2 : (X,Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand each trip is a time-series of (x,y) coordinates. I would suggest following design of schema:

`Row key = shardKey + tripId + timestamp`, and each row has `x` and `y` columns. 
Shard key can be `(tripId % number of regions)`, which prevents hot spotting.
This will allow to retrieve data for each trip via single scan from one region.

Comment: If I understand well, it corresponds approximately to the first possibility that I explain ? And, I don't understand what is the shardKey and the timestamp ?

Comment: If your tripId is incremental, this will lead to hot spotting on you region servers and the whole idea of distributed load won't work. Sharding key prevents this.Then, as I understand each point (x,y) is generated at some point in time, thus has a timestamp. This way you can track position at any point of time.